# What NAS have better transfer speeds?

Tags: nas

When I transfer files to my [Netgear Stora](http://www.netgear.com/stora), I generally get between ~500-1000kbps.

It appears to be a [known problem](https://superuser.com/questions/12103/what-might-limit-data-transfer-rate-to-nas).

Do any NAS exist which can copy at a faster rate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommand this awesome website: http://www.smallnetbuilder.com
And more specifically: http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/component/option,com_nas/Itemid,190

All the answer for NAS are around there

However, the speed is limited by several factors:

- speed of the drives of the NAS
- ethernet interface of the NAS (Gigabit enabled?)
- Your personal network, including switches etc ...
- the ethernet client's interface (Gigabit too?)
- The horrors like Finder/Explorer that reduces the speed transfer (Command line rules or SuperCopier on Windows)

Hope it helps

Comment: Also if you are copying many small files rather than few large ones speed is going to be slow due to both network and disk latency no matter what solution you use. Disk latency can be reduced significantly by using SSD drives but this is obviously more expensive.